# Redirect URL through AWS Lambda

Tags: .htaccess, amazon-web-services, redirect, aws-lambda

I am trying to track emails that get opened. I am using AWS API gateway and Lambda as the back end and am tacking through a 1x1 pixel attached to the email.

Currently my lambda function simply returns a location to the actual image in which I want to redirect to. I will be adding a counter increment to my database using this lambda function once the redirect is functioning (Email tracking):

```
def handler(event, context):
Location = 'https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/stylezz.biz/email-sig/1.png'
return Location
```

In my API gateway I have set up the response to be 301 and mapped the output from the lambda function to my Location header. However the URL does not redirect as simply returns the location in JSON format.:
[image]

Anyone know how I can actually get the API to redirect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Define a method response with status 302, and a “Location” header defined
2) Define a “default” integration response mapping with blank regex, mapping to 302.
3) For this response, define a “Location” header mapping from the redirect URL returned in your Lambda function. i.e. “integration.response.body.location”
3) Configure your lambda function to return the redirect location in the body, i.e.

swagger example:

```
/lambdaredirect-default:
    get:
      produces:
      - "application/json"
      parameters: []
      responses:
        200:
          description: "200 response"
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/Empty"
          headers: {}
        302:
          description: "302 response"
          headers:
            Location:
              type: "string"
      x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
        responses:
          default:
            statusCode: "302"
            responseParameters:
              method.response.header.Location: "integration.response.body.location"
        uri: "arn:aws:apigateway:us-east-1:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:[ACCOUNT_ID]:function:redirect-default/invocations"
        httpMethod: "POST"
        type: "aws"
```

lambda function

```
exports.handler = function(event, context) {
    context.succeed({
        location : "https://example.com"
    });
};
```

Read more [here](https://rpgreen.wordpress.com/2016/01/04/how-to-http-redirects-with-api-gateway-and-lambda/)